# why space between form.validate and .ng-invalid-emal.ng-dirty

Tags: css, angularjs

In an AngularJS application for stylesheet I don't understand where there is a space between "form.validate" and ".ng-invalid-email.ng-dirty":

```
<style>
    form.validate .ng-invalid-required.ng-dirty {background-color: lightpink;}
    form.validate .ng-invalid-email.ng-dirty {
        background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    }
    div.error { color: red; font-weight: bold;}
</style>
```

Any hint or help would be greatly appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

Those are css selectors.

`form.validate` is a selector for any form that has the `.validate` class on it. `.ng-invalid-required.ng-dirty` matches any element with both `.ng-invalid-required` and `.ng-dirty` classes on it.

It's the same as writing the following in a css file:

```
.class1.class2 {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Angular will classes to elements that are in a certain state (invalid, valid, etc) and allow you to define how those states will be defined stylistically. Maybe you change the color, bold them, underline them, add an asterisk, etc. They're just hooks to simplify your life when using ng.

Answer (score 0):

Because `form.validate .ng-invalid-email.ng-dirty` means something with both the ng-invalid-email class and the ng-dirty class on it that is inside a form with the validate class on it, which is what is wanted here.

Without the space it would select a form with all three of the validate, ng-invalid-email and ng-dirty classes on it.

The space indicates a descendant element within the selector syntax. [This MDN page has more on that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).